# Mix ascending and descending sorting in conditional sorting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have one table for two different kind of news. I want to create a list of them ordered by a date which depends of the type of news, so I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY case type
              when 'news' then creation_date 
              else 'events' then starting_date
         end desc;
```

What I want is to sort news by `creation_date ASC` and events by `starting_date DESC`. I tried to simply add

```
when 'news' then creation_date ASC
else 'events' then starting_date DESC
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me, can you add an example how do you want the result to be sorted?

Comment: News are always in the past and events in the future. We want to display closest news and events. Using the first SELECT I got the farthest events on top and then the news and events mixed by the right date. But I need to display first the event closest to today. Then news should be ordered by creation date DESC (ups, I said it the other way around), the ones with bigger dates should appear first, while events are the opposite way, smaller dates appear first.

Is it clearer this way? I really had a hard time trying to understand what my boss wants.

Comment: Can you use `row_number()`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do two separate queries, each sorted its own way. To sort, it needs to be able to compare any item to any other item, and decide which comes first. It has no way to compare a 'news' item to an 'event' item and get a meaningful result.

Comment: +1 There are a multitude of "valid" sorts where creation date of the news items are ascending, and events are descending, depending upon their interleaving. You'll need to specify this more clearly, otherwise the most obvious solution would be to sort one and union it with the other.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

```
SELECT 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_date) AS order_column,
    creation_date,
    type,
    other_columns
FROM my_table 
WHERE type='news'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starting_date) AS order_column,
    starting_date, 
    type,
    other_columns
FROM my_table 
WHERE type='events' 
ORDER BY order_column
```

Important is the minus before second UNIX_TIMESTAMP function. It will result with the events sorted descending and then all news sorted ascending. I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

will something like this work?

```
select m.*, 
       case type
          when 'news' then 
             creation_date 
          when 'events' then 
             starting_date
       end as sort_date
from my_table m
order by sort_date desc
```

Comment: It will sort both descending, while it should be one ascending and one descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.*, 
       case type
          when 'news' then 
             creation_date 
       end as sort_date_1,
       case type
          when 'events' then 
             starting_date
       end as sort_date_2
from my_table m
order by type desc, sort_date_1 asc nulls last, sort_date_2 desc nulls last
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...  
    row_number() over (order by
        case when type = 'news'  then creation_date end asc,
        case when type = 'event' then starting_date end desc) as rn
...
order by rn, type desc,
    case when type = 'news' then creation_date else starting_date end asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order by type,
    case when type = 'news'  then creation_date end desc,
    case when type = 'event' then starting_date end asc
```